# how Write a function that print integers between two numbers

Tags: r

I want Write a function n that accepts two numeric arguments x and
y, and prints all integers between x and y in decreasing order.
example:

- function(5.7,5.9) will not print any integer
- function(3.4,6.5) will print :6,5,4
- function(10,3.5) will print :10,9,8,7,6,5,4

I tried this but it does not give what I'm looking for:

```
Integers <- function(x, y) {

  for(i in y:x) {
    print(floor(i))
  }
}
Integers(8.7, 8.9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a couple of checks before entring the loop

```
Integers <- function(x, y) {
  
  max <- floor(max(x, y))
  min <- ceiling(min(x, y))
  
  if( max < min ) { return() }
  for(i in max:min) {
    print(floor(i))
  }
}

Integers(8.7, 8.9)
Integers(5.7, 5.9)
Integers(3.4, 6.5)
Integers(10, 3.5)
```

---

Another approach without using `floor`, and without explicitly writing a for loop.

```
Integers <- function(x, y) {
  
  upper <- (max(x, y) %/% 1)
  lower <- ((min(x, y) + 1 ) %/% 1)
  
  if( upper > lower )
    cat(upper:lower)
}
```

The `%/% 1` operation is essentially the same as `floor()`, but more verbose.

Comment: Re. "only looking for loop answer" makes this sound a lot like homework. Also, it misses a major point: R has many facilities to perform looping WITHOUT having the user initialize global vars, start iterations at the appropriate index, count iterations, and perform various termination checks. This vastly decreases the probability of various indexing and counting errors when defining, initializing, and running loops. sum(c(1,2,3)) is every bit as much a loop construct to sum numbers as a loop initializing a global var and iteratively updating it till a sum is achieved.

Comment: It may well be homework, but the OP gave a clear question definition, expected outcome, and some code they were having trouble with. So to me that more than meets the criteria for a valid SO question.

Comment: True. That's why I didn't downvote or any such thing. Still, learning to think in R is important as well.  The more debatable point maybe is I submit that processing lists value-by-value in IS looping. The looping is simply taken care of under the hood.

Comment: just want  to learn all the way we can do it, if is there another way to do it without using floor?

Comment: "learning to think in R is important" This is very true. @JohnGarland I've added another approach, replacing `floor` with `%/% 1`, although I find it harder to read & reason about. `floor` is obvious what it's doing.